# have encountered an error while writing a sql query in my IDE, IntelliJ, do you guys know how to fix this?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have been programing a program in javafx using IntelliJ that works with a SQL database (running on 8.0.21 SQL).

This is the error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(VALUES: '1', '1', '1', '1')' at line 1

Here is my class that gives the issue:

```
public class dbHandler extends Configuration {

    java.sql.Connection Connection;

    public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort + "/" + dbName;

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dbUser, dbPass);

        return Connection;

    }

    public void signUp(User user) {

        String insert = "INSERT INTO " + Constants.USERS_TABLE + "(" + Constants.USERS_FIRSTNAME + "," + Constants.USERS_LASTNAME + "," +
                Constants.USERS_USERNAME + "," + Constants.USERS_PASSWORD + ")" + "VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

        try {

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(insert);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getLastName());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getUsername());
            preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getPassword());

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public void newUser(String firstName, String lastName, String username, String password) {

        String insert = "INSERT INTO " + Constants.USERS_TABLE + "("  + Constants.USERS_FIRSTNAME + ", "
                + Constants.USERS_LASTNAME + ", " + Constants.USERS_USERNAME + ", "
                + Constants.USERS_PASSWORD + "(VALUES: ?, ?, ?, ?)"; //mainly this

        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(insert);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, firstName);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, lastName);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, username);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, password);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public class dbHandler extends Configuration {

    java.sql.Connection Connection;

    public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort + "/" + dbName;

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dbUser, dbPass);

        return Connection;

    }

    public void signUp(User user) {

        String insert = "INSERT INTO " + Constants.USERS_TABLE + "(" + Constants.USERS_FIRSTNAME + "," + Constants.USERS_LASTNAME + "," +
                Constants.USERS_USERNAME + "," + Constants.USERS_PASSWORD + ")" + "VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

        try {

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(insert);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getLastName());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getUsername());
            preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getPassword());

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public void newUser(String firstName, String lastName, String username, String password) {

        String insert = "INSERT INTO " + Constants.USERS_TABLE + "("  + Constants.USERS_FIRSTNAME + ", "
                + Constants.USERS_LASTNAME + ", " + Constants.USERS_USERNAME + ", "
                + Constants.USERS_PASSWORD + "(VALUES: ?, ?, ?, ?)"; //mainly this

        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(insert);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, firstName);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, lastName);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, username);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, password);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

`}`
```

I put all the class just in case because I am not very aware why this is giving me an error. If you guys know what the error is it would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: `String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort + "/" + dbName;` So where do you get those variables from?

Comment: looks like this:  `"(VALUES: ?,`  should be `") VALUES ( ?,`   (that's a first glance without actually debugging.  For trouble shooting dynamically generated SQL, consider displaying/logging the generated SQL text  i.e. the contents of (String) insert  ... the actual SQL statement being sent to the database

Comment: @spencer7593, I see that in a couple of the queries. Good catch.

Comment: This does not seem to be related to `JavaFX`.

Comment: @spencer7593 thanks dude! I appreciate your time and effort spent on helping me.

Comment: java naming conventions please